# laravel 7 pdf-to-text | Could not read pdf file

Tags: pdf, laravel-7, pdftotext

I installed this laravel package to convert pdf file into text. https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

I'm getting this error:

> Could not read `sample_1610656868.pdf`

I tried passing the file statically by putting it in public  folder and by giving path of uploaded file.

Here's my controller:

```
public function pdftotext(Request $request)
{

    if($request->hasFile('file'))
    {
        // Get the file with extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        //Get the file name
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        //Get the ext
        $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //File name to store
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        //Upload File
        $path = $request->file('file')->storeAS('public/ebutifier/pdf', $fileNameToStore);
    }
    
    // dd($path);

    $location = public_path($path);

    // $pdf = $request->input('file');

    // dd($location);
    // echo Pdf::getText($location, 'usr/bin/pdftotext');

    $text = (new Pdf('public/ebutifier/pdf/'))
            ->setPdf($fileNameToStore)
            ->text();

            return $text;
}
```

Not sure why it's not working any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Nargesh
Did you get the solution?
I faced the same issue.

Comment: I did not got any solution and the feature was removed for the app.

Answer (score 0):

You used spatie/pdf-to-text Package.
I also tried to use this package but it gave me this kind of error.

So, I used asika/pdf2text package and it worked properly
[Asika/pdf2text pacakge](https://packagist.org/packages/asika/pdf2text)

And this is my code

```
 $path = public_path('/uploads/documents/'. $file_name);  
 $reader = new \Asika\Pdf2text; 
 $output = $reader->decode($path); 
 dd($output);
```

Hopefully, it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I'll try with new app.

Comment: @NargeshRana - I tried to use Asika, but I am getting a blank output. I am using the same code and uploading a proper pdf with lots of text. Any idea why so ?

Comment: @Vivek I think the library does not work. I was not able to solve the error. I have't added the feature in my app because of that.